# Anyone have any opinions on DataTable.Load(DataReader) method?

Tags: performance, ado.net

Does anyone have any thoughts on this method?  I have did some performance testing on it and it seems to perform worse than simply doing a dataadapter.fill call or just looping through the datareader and creating new rows for the table.  Do people use this in production, or is this just another thing Microsoft gave us that we don't use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use it in production code, never really seen bad performance because of it.

In reflector it looks like they both use the adapter.FillFromReader method, so I wonder why there is a difference is performance. I don't see any difference, would gues one is multi threaded or something.